# Using OUTPUT INSERTED.id to UPDATE (i.e. not insert new record) existing rows

Tags: sql-server, update, bulk-insert, cursors, output-clause

1.) @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR has fields (x, y, OrdersTableID) and values:

```
[a,b,Null], [c,d,Null], [e,f,Null]
```

2.) Goal is to bulk insert @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR data into an OrdersTable having fields (id, x, y) with each ORDERS_TABLE.id (aka identity) returned to ***update***  @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR to make the values:

```
[a,b,1], [c,d,2], [e,f,3]
```

3.) But using OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR ***adds*** new rows to @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR yielding values:

```
[a,b,Null], [a,b,Null], [a,b,Null], [NULL,NULL,1], [NULL,NULL,2], [NULL,NULL,3]
```

4.) I can't find a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#inserting-data-returned-from-an-output-clause-into-a-table) option or non-kludgy strategy to ***UPDATE*** the existing rows. Specifically I don't want to trust a `( LAST_INSERT_@@SCOPE_IDENTITY - count(MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR.id) )` while [echoing to a new #temptable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191146/using-source-columns-in-output-into-clause-of-an-insert-statement-sql-server?rq=1) or a `CURSOR/LOOP to INSERT then UPDATE with @@SCOPE_IDENTITY` seems to defeat the whole purpose of **OUTPUT INSERTED**.

Comment: Do the columns `x, y` in `@MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR` always contain unique combination of values?

Comment: YES, the columns x, y in @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR always contain a unique combination of values.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of two things.

Insert all inserted values into a holding table variable and then update the original table variable with the inserted values such as this code below -

```
DECLARE @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR TABLE
(
    x CHAR(1)
  , y CHAR(1)
  , OrdersTableID INT
);

DECLARE @HOLDING_TABLE TABLE
(
    x CHAR(1)
  , y CHAR(1)
  , OrdersTableID INT
);

INSERT INTO @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR
(
    x
  , y
  , OrdersTableID
)
VALUES
('a', 'b', NULL)
, ('c', 'd', NULL)
, ('e', 'f', NULL);

CREATE TABLE #Orders_Table
(
    OrdersTableID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , x CHAR(1)
  , y CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #Orders_Table
OUTPUT Inserted.x
     , Inserted.y
     , Inserted.OrdersTableID
INTO @HOLDING_TABLE
SELECT mrt.x
     , mrt.y
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt;

UPDATE mrt
SET mrt.OrdersTableID = ht.OrdersTableID
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt
    INNER JOIN @HOLDING_TABLE AS ht
        ON ht.x = mrt.x
           AND ht.y = mrt.y;

SELECT mrt.x
     , mrt.y
     , mrt.OrdersTableID
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt;

SELECT ot.OrdersTableID
     , ot.x
     , ot.y
FROM #Orders_Table AS ot;

DROP TABLE #Orders_Table;
```

That gives me these results -

```
-- @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR
x    y    OrdersTableID
---- ---- -------------
a    b    1
c    d    2
e    f    3

-- #Orders_Table
OrdersTableID x    y
------------- ---- ----
1             a    b
2             c    d
3             e    f
```

Or insert the values into @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR, self-join on x and y, and delete the records where OrdersTableID is null like this -

```
DECLARE @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR TABLE
(
    x CHAR(1)
  , y CHAR(1)
  , OrdersTableID INT
);

INSERT INTO @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR
(
    x
  , y
  , OrdersTableID
)
VALUES
('a', 'b', NULL)
, ('c', 'd', NULL)
, ('e', 'f', NULL);

CREATE TABLE #Orders_Table
(
    OrdersTableID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , x CHAR(1)
  , y CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #Orders_Table
OUTPUT Inserted.x
     , Inserted.y
     , Inserted.OrdersTableID
INTO @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR
SELECT mrt.x
     , mrt.y
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt;

DELETE mrt
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt
    INNER JOIN @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt2
        ON mrt2.x = mrt.x
           AND mrt2.y = mrt.y
WHERE mrt.OrdersTableID IS NULL;

SELECT mrt.x
     , mrt.y
     , mrt.OrdersTableID
FROM @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR AS mrt;

SELECT ot.OrdersTableID
     , ot.x
     , ot.y
FROM #Orders_Table AS ot;

DROP TABLE #Orders_Table;
```

Both generate the same results, but this second solution requires that there is no pk set on @MULTIPLE_RESULTS_TABLEVAR for values x and y.